# how to identify the dynamically created UIImageView by tag

Tags: iphone

```
    if([imageview superview])
{
    [imageview removeFromSuperview];
    [myView addSubview:imageview];  
}
else if([imageview superview])
{
    [imageview removeFromSuperview];
    [myView addSubview:imageview];  
}
else if([imageview superview])
{
    [imageview removeFromSuperview];
    [myView addSubview:imageview];}
```

Here I dynamically create multiple imageviews and set tag values and add it as a subview to the UIView. I need to identify which imageview is in superview position and remove it and add another by tapping it.

Comment: if you view with tag option it will help to you

Comment: Is it only me or anybody notice all the if conditions are exactly same which makes this question very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get your image view by its tag value then you can :

```
UIImageView *tempView = [self.view viewWithTag:yourTag];
```

make sure your tag value is valid id for the image view.

Hope it gives you an idea...

Comment: i create multiple imageview with tag dynamicaly and it to the view as subview...I need to identify which imageview is in superview position by using tag value....its a comic project,i need to change the pages by checking superview.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView* tempView = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:yourImageViewTag];
if([tempView superview])
    [tempView removeFromSuperview];
```